# JavaScript - how to keep last submitted value in select box (dynamically generated select box)

Tags: javascript, php, html

can you please help(or point me to right direction) in order to modify following code? I would like to keep value in second selection box (id="detail") once the form is submitted. As you can see, the second box is dynamically generated via JavaScript.
thank you ..

```
    <form method="get" action="index.php">

    <script>
            function configureDropDownLists(aa,detail) {
                var colours = ['red', 'green'];
                var cars = ['audi', 'fiat'];


                switch (aa.value) {
                    case 'colours':
                        detail.options.length = 0;
                        for (i = 0; i < colours.length; i++) {
                            createOption(detail, colours[i], colours[i]);
                        }
                        break;
                    case 'cars':
                        detail.options.length = 0; 
                        for (i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
                            createOption(detail, cars[i], cars[i]);
                        }
                        break;

                    default:
                        detail.options.length = 0;
                        break;
                }
            }

            function createOption(object, text, value) {
                var opt = document.createElement('option');
                opt.value = value;
                opt.text = text;
                object.options.add(opt);
            }
        </script>


        <select id="object" name="objects" onchange="configureDropDownLists(this,document.getElementById('detail'))">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option <?php if ($_GET['objects'] == 'colours') { ?>selected="true" <?php }; ?>value="colours">colours</option>
            <option <?php if ($_GET['objects'] == 'cars') { ?>selected="true" <?php }; ?>value="cars">cars</option>
        </select>


        <select id="detail">
        </select>


        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit" />

    </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are generating the options dynamically, the options don't even exist after the form is submitted. So I think you should call the function once when the page loads to create them.

Also, you have to give the function that is creating the options the default value that it should set as selected.

Here are the changes I would recommend:

```
<form method="get" action="index.php">

    <script>
            function configureDropDownLists(aa,detail,selected) {
                //alert(selected);
                var colours = ['red', 'green'];
                var cars = ['audi', 'fiat'];


                switch (aa.value) {
                    case 'colours':
                        detail.options.length = 0;
                        for (i = 0; i < colours.length; i++) {
                            createOption(detail, colours[i], colours[i], selected);
                        }
                        break;
                    case 'cars':
                        detail.options.length = 0; 
                        for (i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
                            createOption(detail, cars[i], cars[i], selected);
                        }
                        break;

                    default:
                        detail.options.length = 0;
                        break;
                }
            }

            function createOption(object, text, value, selected) {
                var opt = document.createElement('option');
                opt.value = value;
                opt.text = text;
                opt.selected = (selected == value) ? "selected" : '';
                object.options.add(opt);
            }


        </script>


        <select id="object" name="objects" onchange="configureDropDownLists(this,document.getElementById('detail'),'<?php echo isset($_GET['detail']) ? $_GET['detail'] : ''; ?>')">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option <?php if ($_GET['objects'] == 'colours') { ?>selected="true" <?php }; ?>value="colours">colours</option>
            <option <?php if ($_GET['objects'] == 'cars') { ?>selected="true" <?php }; ?>value="cars">cars</option>
        </select>


        <select id="detail" name="detail">
        </select>


        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit" />

    </form>
<script>
    configureDropDownLists(document.getElementById('object'),document.getElementById('detail'),'<?php echo isset($_GET['detail']) ? $_GET['detail'] : ''; ?>')
</script>
```

Notice the two changes I made. I called the `configureDropDownLists` function at the bottom to dynamically create the options when the page load. And I passed the `$_GET['detail']` variable to the function to set it as the default.

Comment: beautiful, thank you Andrew.. it shows how much I need to learn in order to understand it properly..